# Get self-contained EXE's path?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, registry, console-application

If we're deploying a [single file application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file), is there a way to get the single file application `.exe`'s path from inside our code?

The reason I'm asking is because I have a sample console application, which I'd like to register in the registry to start every time windows starts, but sadly every known API like `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, or the one suggested by Microsoft `AppContext.BaseDirectory` return paths relative to the actual `.dll` file of the console application, not the self-contained `.exe` which unpackages it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13051), suggestion by @Symbai:

```
public static class Extensions {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetModuleFileName(IntPtr hModule, System.Text.StringBuilder lpFilename, int nSize);
    static readonly int MAX_PATH = 255;
    public static string GetExecutablePath() {
        if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows)) {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
            GetModuleFileName(IntPtr.Zero, sb, MAX_PATH);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        else {
            return System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainModule.FileName` is exactly what I was about to suggest